# Interface Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

Why does the code:

```
Hello hello = GreetingUtil.hello();
```

get this error?

```
Incompatible types
Required Hello
Found Greeting
```

Assuming these are the classes/interfaces and I have no control over `Greeting` and `HelloWorld` as they are external APIs, isn't `Hello` is of `Greeting` type?

```
public interface Greeting {
}

public interface Hello extends Greeting {
}

public class HelloWorld implements Greeting {
}

public class GreetingUtil {
    public static Greeting hello() {
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

Or, Am I getting it wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `HelloWorld implements Greeting` and not Hello, if you change it to `HelloWorld implements Hello` should work and `public static Greeting hello() {` to `public static Hello hello() {`

Comment: Because there is no guarantee that a `HelloWorld` implementation would have a `hello()` method.

Comment: `Greeting -> HelloWorld` and `Greeting -> Hello` are both valid inheritance chains here, but they are independent of each other. `HelloWorld` doesn't know about `Hello`. So when your `GreetingUtil` returns an instance of `HelloWorld`, it can't be assigned to `Hello`, even if you try to hide it behind the interface. The compiler knows that not every `Greeting` is a `Hello`.

Comment: So, is there really no way to make `Hello hello = GreetingUtil.hello();` work without modifying `Greeting` and `HelloWorld` or changing it to `Greeting greeting = GreetingUtil.hello();`?

Answer (score 1):

If `Greeting` is not in scope of your application code, then you should change `HelloWorld` to implement `interface Hello` instead :

```
public class HelloWorld implements Hello {
}
```

and then return `Hello` from the `GreetingUtil.hello` method as well :

```
public static Hello hello() {
    return new HelloWorld();
}
```

Comment: But the problem is HelloWorld is an API from external library and I can't modify it.

Comment: @JulezJupiter Then what is `Hello` for? Maybe you can rethink of what exactly you desire as the outcome.

Comment: I want the client to use `Hello` instead of `Greeting` to call the underlying methods implemented in `HelloWorld`.

Answer (score 0):

HelloWorld and Hello are two siblings not parent/child.

The problem is in code:
`Hello hello = GreetingUtil.hello();`

It should have

```
Greeting greeting = greetingUtil.hello();
```

Comment: How do I make `Hello hello = GreetingUtil.hello();` work? I intend to avoid `Greeting greeting = greetingUtil.hello();`. I can't modify Greeting and HelloWorld as they are from external library.

Comment: @JulezJupiter If all the stuff are from API and only the creation is written by you, you **have** to use this solution. You cannot write `Bird bird = new Dog();` because *it is wrong*.